# Can't install Ubuntu; PC keeps booting to Windows using USB

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows, usb-drive

The title says it, I've tried nearly everything, changing BIOS boot, installing other apps to write the `.iso` image on my USB, disabling fast start up in power settings etc... but nothing seems to work! I own an Acer Travelmate 5742Z with windows 10, did I maybe mess it up because I first opened the `.iso` image with the photo app? (I know, it was a very dumb thing to do, but im not a computer expert and it was 3 am so I thought the `.iso` image was the install command)

Comment: Make sure Secure Boot is disabled in your BIOS settings. Keep UEFI boot. Try using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to create the USB. Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities for PC keeps booting to Windows :

1. Check your first boot option in BIOS set to USB
2. Make sure you format your USB properly
3. Check if your ios missing something

I like to suggest you to make bootable CD and try again if still want to try with USB try this...

1. Make bootable USB with UNetbootin (its very simple or see this http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).
2. Go to BIOS and set USB for first boot.
3. After second step when PC going to restart after black screen keep pressing F8 till black or blue screen will appear.
4. You can see option on screen like Try ubutnu, install ubuntu and etc...
5. Enter on Try ubuntu
6. It takes aprox 5 min to start (Just wait do not press anything)
7. One you reach on desktop you can try environment or just click Install Ubuntu icon on desktop.

Here you get how to install Ubuntu http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop